# HTML css, <p>aragraph text larger than code when two lines on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, font-size, paragraph

I'm having trouble with a very strange quirk on iOS: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k72ae/)

When on iOS, these two lines become 24px, but the css codes for 16px. When I remove the bottom paragraph, the remaining paragraph suddenly becomes 16px again.

```
<br/>This is interesting</p>
<p>second line</p>
```

I'm testing it out in the iOS simulator by the way.

Thanks

Edit: to be clear, this problem does not occur on a desktop browser I can see

Comment: I don't have an iPhone, but I just want to remark that the text in the fiddle is invisible on non-webkit browsers.

Comment: @MrLister Hmm that is even more strange. I'm not using anything fancy, am I? The font falls back on a sans-serif, might any of the other not be available..

Comment: You have `background: -webkit-gradient(...)` as the only background color; this will be ignored by Firefox et al, so the text color and the background color are both white.